# Preview of an AlertDialog doesn't work in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-preview

### Problem description

I'm trying to see a preview of my `AlertDialog` in compose but I'm not getting it, the preview doesn't render it even though it doesn't show any error. I'm sure the problem is only with this composable function because I can see the preview of other functions normally.

#### Warning

I'm getting this warning, but I don't understand very well if it's a problem that doesn't render my dialog.

[image]

#### Works normally in runtime

My dialog appears normally in an execution environment, which leads me to believe that it is really a problem with the preview function:

[image]

### My code

#### Compose related versions

I'm using `build.gradle.kts` files and I reference my compose related versions like this:

```kotlin
object Compose {
    const val composeVersion = "1.0.5"
    const val composeCompilerVersion = "1.0.5"
    const val material = "androidx.compose.material:material:$composeVersion"
    const val ui = "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$composeVersion"
    const val uiTooling = "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$composeVersion"
    const val uiToolingPreview = "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$composeVersion"
    const val runtime = "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime:$composeVersion"
    const val compiler = "androidx.compose.compiler:compiler:$composeCompilerVersion"

    private const val navigationVersion = "2.4.0-beta02"
    const val navigation = "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:$navigationVersion"

    private const val hiltNavigationComposeVersion = "1.0.0-beta01"
    const val hiltNavigationCompose = "androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:$hiltNavigationComposeVersion"

    private const val activityComposeVersion = "1.4.0"
    const val activityCompose = "androidx.activity:activity-compose:$activityComposeVersion"

    private const val lifecycleVersion = "2.4.0"
    const val viewModelCompose = "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:$lifecycleVersion"
}
```

#### Component that renders the dialog

```kotlin
@Composable
fun InvalidValuesDialog(
    @StringRes title: Int,
    @StringRes message: Int,
    @StringRes buttonText: Int,
    checkBoxIsChecked: Boolean,
    onCheckChange: () -> Unit,
    onDismissRequest: () -> Unit,
    buttonClick: () -> Unit,
) {
    val spaces = LocalSpacing.current
    AlertDialog(
        onDismissRequest = onDismissRequest,
        title = {
            Text(
                text = stringResource(id = title),
                fontSize = 20.sp
            )
        },
        text = {
            Column {
                Text(
                    text = stringResource(id = message),
                    fontSize = 18.sp
                )
                VerticalSpacer(spaces.small)
                Row(
                    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
                ) {
                    Checkbox(checked = checkBoxIsChecked, onCheckedChange = { onCheckChange() })
                    HorizontalSpacer(spaces.extraSmall)
                    Text(
                        modifier = Modifier.clickable { onCheckChange() },
                        text = stringResource(id = R.string.keep_value_informed),
                        fontSize = 16.sp
                    )
                }
            }
        },
        buttons = {
            Button(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                onClick = buttonClick
            ) {
                Text(text = stringResource(id = buttonText))
            }
        }
    )
}
```

#### Preview function

```kotlin
@Composable
@Preview
fun InvalidValuesDialogCheckedPreview() {
    CalorieTrackerTheme {
        InvalidValuesDialog(
            title = R.string.high_height,
            message = R.string.high_height_message,
            buttonText = R.string.next,
            checkBoxIsChecked = true,
            onCheckChange = {},
            onDismissRequest = {},
            buttonClick = {}
        )
    }
}
```

##### Preview result

[image]

### My attempt fails

I figured the dialog might not be rendering due to it not being big enough to show on the screen. So I decided to put it inside a `Box` with maximum screen size, but it still didn't work.

```kotlin
@Composable
@Preview(showBackground = true)
fun InvalidValuesDialogCheckedPreview() {
    CalorieTrackerTheme {
        Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
            InvalidValuesDialog(
                title = R.string.high_height,
                message = R.string.high_height_message,
                buttonText = R.string.next,
                checkBoxIsChecked = true,
                onCheckChange = {},
                onDismissRequest = {},
                buttonClick = {}
            )
        }
    }
}
```

##### Attempt fails result

[image: White screen preview]

Comment: Maybe [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69173919/how-to-make-a-preview-of-a-dialog-in-jetpack-compose) can help you

Comment: I had seen this question before but it was not very helpful to me :(
Thanks for try help me :)

Answer (score 4):

**The preview window doesn't support multiple windows**
I think the error is valid, and it is not possible still to see Toast or snackbar either in the preview or preview interactive mode.

BTW, I think when you're using **androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling** you don't need anymore to **androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview**

Comment: Hi! Thanks for trying to help me. It seems to me that for the time being it is really impossible to have a preview of this type of composable. Thanks for the dependency suggestion.